# Return value of std::filesystem::create_directories() on paths with trailing slash

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, std-filesystem

GCC (10.0.1) and Clang (11.0.0)/MSVC (VS 16.4.3) show different behavior concerning std::filesystem::create_directories() when a non-existing path with a trailing slash is given as argument.

More precisely, while all three compilers indeed create the directory, the latter two return false in that case, making the return value of std::filesystem::create_directories() ambigous (and counter-intuitive).

Specifically, if no file exists at path "a/b/c", then the following program,

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::filesystem::create_directories("a/b/c/");
}
```

creates a directory at that path, but prints false under Clang/MSVC while true under GCC.

Which is the correct behavior?

Comment: Are you sure that in each case the preconditions are the same?  That is, ether `a/b/c` always exists or `a/b/c` never exist?  The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) states `"Return value: true if a directory was created for the directory p resolves to, false otherwise"`.  Indeed, on the box I'm working on calling `create_directories` twice in succession on the same path returns `true` on the first call and `false` on the second.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, that it is not an issue of preconditions and in my opinion GCC is right, but my guess is, that clarification of the standard on that point would be helpful.

For a long time it is quite common usage pattern to mark directories with a trailing separator, to distinguish them from files. And I would expect an implementation of `std::filesystem::create_directories` to return true if a path about to be created is not existing before the call, and exists after the call, as a result of the call.

Let's extend the example a little bit:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

int main() {
    std::error_code ec;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::filesystem::exists("a/b/c/") << "/";
    std::cout << std::filesystem::create_directories("a/b/c/", ec) << "/";
    std::cout << !!ec << "/" << std::filesystem::exists("a/b/c/");
}
```

Now we can use godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/5883uY

And it shows for GCC/libstdc++ `false/true/false/true` as we would expect, it doesn't exist, it was created by the `create_directories` call, there was no error and it exists after that.

Now clang/libc++ results in `false/false/false/true`, so it didn't exists, it tells us it didn't create it, but it did, there is no error, and we have prove after the call.

Looking into the github version of MSVC stl, it looks like it calls `CreateDirectoryW` with: `a`, `a\b`, `a\b\c` and finally `a\b\c\`, and that last one reports `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, which leads to the return of `false` as it seemed we didn't do anything, but I think that is an implementation detail bleeding out of the function.
My guess is, the Clang code works similar, but I didn't check the libc++ source yet.

And the standard reads: *"Returns: true if a new directory was created, otherwise false. The signature with argument ec returns false if an error occurs."*

So the standard wants `true` if *a directory* was created, not the last one, and for the *ec* variant `false` signals an error, yet clang tells us via `ec` there was none.

I might still be wrong, as I'm not in any WG, but my conclusion: GCC is right, and it seems like a bug in MSVC and Clang.

As I already collected [discrepancies](https://gulrak.net/posts/2019-std-filesystem-corner-cases/) between the implementations while verifying my own one, I'll "happily" add this one to my collection, if that's okay.

**Update:** I just dug into the other sources and Clang/libc++ works with a recursive `parent_path()` based mechanism that in the end leads to the same sequence like MSVC where the last `::mkdir("a/b/c/")` was preceded by a `::mkdir("a/b/c")` so it reports false as it assumes it didn't create the directories.